# jQuery UI Tabs loses css and scripts

Tags: jquery-ui, dom, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a problem here with [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). What I'm trying to do is that everytime the user clicks on a tab, I load the content of the tab with Ajax using jQuery.load() function. The problem I'm having is that, after a call to $().load(), I lose all the css and javascript that was part of the DOM before (and YES I use .live). So I have something like this:

```
$("selector").live("mouseup", function(){

    $("tab_id").load("path #tab_id");

});
```

So, normally the code above should load the content of my tab `#tab_id` into the DIV of my tab, which it does, the only problem I'm having is that I lose all the styles and javascript that was present on that specific part of the page before. Any idea how I could fix this issue?

Thank you

**EDIT** : Here is an illustration of the problem I'm trying to talk about [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c_fiddler/92Gbz/4/). As you can see, initially the content of my Div `#content` is green (as specified in the stylesheet, but after I load it with Ajax (by clicking on either Tab 1 or Tab 2 or Tab 3, I lose the css (my paragraph is no longer green)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without the markup to know why you're losing styles, but I think the functionality you're implementing is [built into jquery ui already](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax).

Comment: I don't experience the same behavior in chrome or IE

Answer (score 0):

The styles are probably linked to original context of the content.  But like menacingly said, it'd be difficult to know without the markup/css.  JSFiddle could help us out a whole lot.

I'm assuming the CSS is like this

```
#tab-container .tab-item { style };
```

Then, when you move the tab content to your div, it no longer has the original context for CSS to work properly.

I would then just add the proper CSS markup

```
#tab-container .tab-item, #content-container .tab-item { style };
```